# Granting read access to /system/ directory to System app in AOSP

Tags: android, embedded-linux, android-source

I am developing a system app that will read a file that is created on the system directory when the image is deployed.

The source for the image is managed by us also so we can make whatever modifications are required. The system app itself runs as the system process and I "simply" need to grant read access to the system directory to this user.

Grateful for any pointers on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to this approach, the Vendor partition was used and the permissions to the new files and directories required was granting manually while running in the recovery image.

Answer (score 1):

`/system/` partition is read-only by AOSP design. You shouldn't create a file on the system directory. Seems it's worth reviewing your app design.

Check related answer:
[Android 10 prevents apps or pretty much anything from mounting system as R/W. Yes, even if you are rooted.](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220920/363009)

Comment: Thanks for that link, we have a particularly niche implementation that basically required storing some files in a non volatile partition that we could guarantee would be available on first boot. We were actually able to achieve this using the Vendor partition and granting permissions to these files manually while running in recovery.